# Rails 4 using different db with different tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

Seem's that i have one little question-trouble:

i have my rails application on server, let's say name A, and i use there all tables(let's say table1, table2).... But now i need to buy one more server, name B.  And from there i must use some tables too (let's say table3, table4).

**Is it really to use in rails two different db, from different server's? And how to do this? What to write than in ActiveModel files ?**

Now i simple have database.yml with one db. How to set up some edit, as i say in question?

Comment: @AnthonyHorne no, this is own project

Comment: Rails does not support using different databases. I suggest going for a db level solution: using MySQL you can take a look to [federated storage engines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-storage-engine.html). If you migrate to PostgreSQL you can use [PG's foreign data wrappers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/postgres-fdw.html)

Comment: I say database.yml, that is why I thought so.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible

In database YML:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: app_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost


aux_development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: aux_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

All your models will use 'development' database. If you want one of them to use 'aux_development' just:

```
class OtherModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "aux_#{Rails.env}"
end
```

Comment: also please give advice: how it depend on load speed ?

Comment: so what about speed?\

Comment: sorry for the delay. I haven't detected any speed issues. You application will open two different connections, so it won't close one to open the other